# How to process files with purely numerical extenson [ regex ] Windows

Tags: windows, batch, regex

Windows, batch.
I want to process files in batch for loop. The problem is:I have no idea what exactly the extension will be. What I do know is that it will be a number.

So what I'm trying to create is something like this:

```
@echo off
For %%X in ("%cd%\*.[0-9]+") do (
  processFile.vbs %%X %%X.csv
  sed -i s/\/t/;/g %%X.csv
  sed -i s/,/:/g %%X.csv
)
```

But regex like I put down in the for loop doesn't seem to work in Windows.

Comment: Do you really need to do this as batch script when there is powershell? Which OS does this need to run on?

Comment: That's the problem: I have no idea whether it won't be used on machines without powershell. That's why I'm trying to create a solution for most uses. And it will not be used by me. It is for a colleague who won't know how to react when something wouldn't work.

Comment: Well, every machine since windows vista comes with powershell. Just the powershell version varies between the versions (vista/2008 = v1, w7/2008 R2 = v2, w8/2012 = v3, w8.1/2012 R2 = v4)

Comment: Yeah, well we do use Windows XP on several machines. But ok, I think I'll try the powershell solution first to have at least something and then go and try it in simple batch.

Answer (score 0):

You have to pipe `dir` command output to the `findstr`, which supports [limited set](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490907.aspx) of regular expressions. Source: [Batch Script to delete files based on findstr regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18386164/batch-script-to-delete-files-based-on-findstr-regex)

Unfortunately `+` token is not supported, so here is my best shot (thanks, **Scott**!):

```
@echo off
for /f "tokens=*" %%X in ('dir /b ^| findstr /r /e \.[0-9][0-9]*') do (
    processFile.vbs %%X %%X.csv
    sed -i s/\/t/;/g %%X.csv
    sed -i s/,/:/g %%X.csv
)
```

- `/r` swicth tell `findstr` to search using regex
- `/e` switch matches the pattern at the end of a line

Also, `findstr` is [full of quirks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8844868/what-are-the-undocumented-features-and-limitations-of-the-windows-findstr-comman), so you you've been warned.

Comment: This looks like it will match (find) files with no extension; e.g., `beat.` or `cracker`. The question says, "the extension ... will be a number", and the OP's try to solve it includes `.[0-9]+`, so this might not be exactly what he wants.

Comment: @Scott Yes, but as I've already said, `findstr` doesn't support `+`. So this is the best I can do.

Comment: How about `\.[0-9][0-9]*` (or `\.[0-9]*[0-9]`)?

Comment: Hmm, that could work. My regex voodoo is far from perfect, thanks!